# Allowed types for DataDefinition::create()

Tags: entities, 8

I'm creating a new [Field Type](https://www.drupal.org/node/2302735) in Drupal 8. What types can I pass to [`DataDefinition::create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21DataDefinition.php/function/DataDefinition%3A%3Acreate/8)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The types are defined as [DataType plugins](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Annotation%21DataType.php/class/annotations/DataType/8). You could also implement additional ones, but that's not necessary very often, since all the basic scalar data types exist already.

Comment: Ok, thank you.. I'd like to see some better documentation from Drupal, but for now this is fine :)

Comment: Yeah - an article with an example use of each type would be super helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Do a file search for `@DataType` you will find every data type in the system.