# Allowed column type names and element type names for creating custom Field Types

Tags: entities, 8

I'm creating new [Field Types](https://www.drupal.org/node/2302735) in Drupal 8. 
I [recently asked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197931/allowed-types-for-datadefinitioncreate) which are the type names allowed for the [`DataDefinition::create()`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/197933/60010) method, receiving a [good answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/197933/60010).

Now I figured out that I need at least other two type names:

- A **column** type name to use inside the method [`schema(...)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemInterface.php/function/FieldItemInterface%3A%3Aschema/8) from the `FieldItemBase` class.
- Another type name to create **elements** inside the method [`formElement(...)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetInterface.php/function/WidgetInterface%3A%3AformElement/8) from the class `WidgetBase`.

For example this is a snippet of code used to create a new Field Type, defining the `schema()` method:

```
public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $fd) {

  $columns = array(

    // 

    // Here the column type name is 'varchar'
    'password' => array(
      'description' => 'A plain text password.',
      'type' => 'varchar',
    ),

    // 

  );

  $schema = array(
    'columns' => $columns,
    'indexes' => array(),
    'foreign keys' => array(),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

In the above code the **column type name** is `'varchar'`.

And this is another snippet, defining the `formElement` method (always used defining the Field Type):

```
public function formElement(
  FieldItemListInterface $items, 
  $delta, 
  array $element, 
  array &$form, 
  FormStateInterface $form_state
) {

  //

  // Here the element type name is 'password'
  $element['passwordlist'] = array(
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#title' => t('Password'),
    '#description' => t('Select a password for the user'),
  );

  //

  return $element;
}
```

In the above code the **element type name** is `'password'`.

What can I use for `'type'` in the first case and `'#type'` in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All available schema types are listed in the following table:
https://www.drupal.org/node/159605

Here is a list of available types of render elements (first column of the table corresponds to the #type property of the element)
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements